# jupyter could not remember I have imported tensorflow in the last block

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter, tensorflow2.0

When I was using jupyter in vscode, I found that it could not remember remember I had import tensorflow in the last block. like:

```
block1: import tensorflow as tf  (success)
block2: print(tf.__version) (false -->"name 'tf' is not defined")
```

This problem is only for tensorflow. Vscode works well with other modules.

I am using Apple M1 max

Answer (score 1):

**Restart** Jupyter kernel will lose all variables. After I restart it then only run `print(tf.__version__)` i get the same error as yours:

[image]

After restarting, you should run the previous code cell again to make the following code run successfully.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!  Just restarting did not work in my case. It seems that this problem only occurs with TensorFlow. When I import pandas, it remembers pandas in the next block.

Comment: @xinwang. Can you run `pip show tensorflow` to check if it exists in current environment? If it does exist, you import successfully in first code cell and don't restart Jupyter but print(tf.__version__) throws errors, please file a report in [VSCode-Juoyter](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues).